# Call the iOS Photo Editing App from my own app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm already picking a photo/video from the Photo Gallery using UIImagePickerController. I'd like to have a button in my own app that will open the default iOS Photo Editor that you have in the Photos App.

[The editor I'm talking about.](https://images.iphonephotographyschool.com/26972/560/iPhone-Camera.jpg)

I've read a lot about [iOS App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2), what they do and how to use them, but from what I've seen, they're used mostly to add an extension (e.g a new filter) to the Photos App Editor and not what I'm looking for.

Can someone point me in the right direction? If there is any (maybe this behaviour is not possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, If you want to use native editing then you can only set :

```
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
```

Secondly, by using share extension you can open photo app using photo from your App but after edit it will not return image to your App.

Last, App extensions are used to work out of App. you have to create own editing filters in App extension and from there you can get back image in shared folder between App and extension, But you cannot use photo App filters. you have to code.

So, Instead of using extension, the same thing you can do within App.

Comment: I've tried "allowsEditing = true" before, but that only offers some basic cropping features. Thank you for your answer, you have confirmed my suspicions about the fact that we actually to code the photo editor or settle with sharing to the Photos App, but not getting the picture back.

Comment: you can use third parties. its better than to code. just google according to your need